# How can I loop on sql request

Tags: sql

I want to have all code of ***prerequis*** (it is a formation too) for a specified formation
and the request(query) work as well but it return me 3 lines differents with each **fo.code** , so the query run successfully with the right data, but actually, it isn't really what I want, I want to have all that **fo.code** inside a single column separated by ' , ' comma.

should I use a loop or what, please need help

```
SELECT formations.id, formations.titre, fo.code
FROM formations
  JOIN prerequis ON formations.id = prerequis.id_formation
  JOIN formations fo ON prerequis.id_formation_requi = fo.id
WHERE formations.id = 24
```

[image]

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (sql server, mysql, oracle, postgres, etc)?  Is that last screenshot the output you are wanting or the output you are getting that you don't want? if the latter, can you share what that same data would look like the way you want it?

Comment: `group_concat()`, `String_Agg()`, `List_Agg()`, `wm_concat()` are some of the functions which may work depending on RDBMS and version.  These are aggregation functions which would allow you to combine like ID and titre and then it would group all the "codes" on one line.

Comment: I'm using mysql,
The screenshot is the output of the query in this question, JNevill
Can you share me the complete request please -XQbert